# Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. firestore/failed-precondition

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, flutter

I am seeing the following error when I try to fetch data to firestore.

[firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. Ensure your query has been indexed via the Firebase console.

I am adding data to the firestore using the following code.

```
firestore().collection("Token").doc().set({ token: token })
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Is firebaseApp initialized?

Comment: Yes, firebaseApp is initialized. I am using firebase simulator. This is an intermittent error.